# How to add SSN to Elastic Beanstalk default url so that it is secure (using https)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to server management and don't know how to make the default elastic beancstalk url to use https. I want to make the server url to be https because I want to hit endpoints through a react app using browser. The browser automatically blocks all http end points.

When I uploaded my node js server to elastic beanstalk, my server got hosted on a link something like this http://exy-env.eba-b3k8jne90.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

The documentation is very confusing and there is no clear step wise answers. If someone has any insisgts then please help me with the procedure.

Thank you.

I have tried it with using load balancer where I imported the SSN of domain I own but when I access the server url with https, I am getting the following error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: "I imported the SSN of domain " - how exactly did you setup your own domain to work with elastic beancstalk? Using Route53?

Comment: I did the request certificate in AWS certificate manager and added the CNAME fields on Netlify for this certificate. Then, I used this certificate in load balaner but since this certificate belongs to my domain not the url of elastic beanstalk, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> since this certificate belongs to my domain not the url of elastic beanstalk, it won't work.

That's exactly how it should work. You should only use your own domain, not elastic beanstalk's url to access your application now.

Comment: But I would be using AWS EC2 for scaling. Server hosted on a domain in Netlify, won't be able to scale up. Maybe I am not understanding it properly. Do you mean, I should switch url on Elastic Beanstank with my domain url? How should that work?

Comment: @tanujgupta "I should switch url on Elastic Beanstank with my domain url?" - yes. That's exactly what you should do.